# Does the execution of an infinite loop in javascript tax only your computer's resources?

Tags: javascript, bash

I'm beginning to learn javascript and I wrote an infinite loop

```
<script>
while(1==true){
    document.write("hello world");
}
</script>
```

I ran `top -d .5` from the commandline and didn't see this script take up CPU.

I then created an infinite loop in .php

```
<?php
    while(1==true){
        echo "Hello World";
    }
?>
```

I ran `top -d .5` from the commandline and saw this .php script take up CPU.

This leads me to believe that when an infinite loop written in javascript runs, it only taxes your computer's resources, not the server's (I guess that's why they call it a client-side language.)  Can someone confirm this?

And more generally, does this mean that all the interpreting of javascript taxes only your computer's resources, not the server's?

Comment: JavaScript is just a language. There're several implementations, including server-side ones like Node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True and true.
When making a loop in PHP wich is server-side you will take up resources from your server. When doing scripting in "javascript" you will use the clients resources, **unless you of course do serverside calls**. In most modern browsers Javascript just uses the browsers memory wich means that you cannot take up all computer resources before your browser will quit on you.

Best regards
Jonas

Comment: +1 best imho best answer cause it points out making calls inside the loop.

Comment: Thank your for the +1 and edit Filburt. Have a wonderfull day. Best regards Jonas

Answer (score 3):

Anything that runs consumes resources where it is running.

In your samples:

- client javascript: takes only resources of the client (it doesn't access any other machine)
- php: the php takes resources of your server

You should also be aware that javascript can run on the server, [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is a good example of server-side javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You are absolutely correct.

**Javascript runs client-side.**

Comment: that's a bit too general... javascript can run on the server-side too (like node.js).

Comment: @Yahia agreed, I was looking for another question that had this topic covered to close. This was just a head's up for the user. The question, IMHO is too broad and obvious for SO.